# Undefined after a check?

Tags: typescript

in following [code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Smth%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20data%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20value%3A%20number%7D%20%7C%20undefined%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20doSmth(i%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20data%20%3D%20this.data%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20data%5Bi%5D%20%26%26%20data%5Bi%5D.value%20%3D%3D%3D%200%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) with `strictNullChecks` turned on I'm getting an error

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.

```
class Smth {
    private data: Array<{ value: number} | undefined> = [];

    public doSmth(i: number) { 
        const data = this.data;
        return data[i] && data[i].value === 0
        //                ^^^^^^^ Object is possibly 'undefined'.
    }
}
```

I can't understand how it can be undefined after a check.

Comment: [Here's the related issue.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11483), TL;DR, typescript won't check this because of the compiler performance cost. In the meantime, you can use a non-null assertion: `data[i]!.value === 0`

Comment: I suggest not to use the same variable name on multiple locations of your code, although is possible to do it, it makes code confusing. You have a constant variable named "data" and also a private member of the class with the same name. Just ask yourself which one are you really using in your code?

Comment: @JonnathanQ, but they refer to the same object.

Comment: @CRice, why not an answer?

Comment: @Qwertiy, I thought there would have been a duplicate for sure and I was going to vote for that after commenting, but now I can't find one. I'll post it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11483) in Typescript.

**TL;DR** of that issue, Typescript *can* make these checks but the devs have chosen not to due to a significant performance cost on the compiler.

The workaround is to use the non-null assertion operator (`!`) to tell the compiler that the value is not `null` or `undefined`. For this example:

```
return data[i] && data[i]!.value === 0
```

Comment: Another way (without using non-null assertion operator) is just to store an array item in its own variable: `const item = this.data[i]; return item && item.value === 0;`